# Access Cisco Call Manager Express on 2811 Router

Tags: cisco, router, vlan, voip

I'm trying to gain access to my business' Cisco 2811.

I did the standard password reset following these procedures: http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/hw/routers/ps259/products_password_recovery09186a0080094675.shtml
I changed the passwords and rebooted.

However, when the system booted back up all but three of the phones returned to their normal state. The other three simply sit at **"Configuring IP"** and never come back online. I've tried erasing the configuration on one and that didn't help at all. The phones are all Cisco 7960s.

I've taken a couple Cisco CCNA exam prep classes but that was a *long* time ago so some of this is coming back to me but some I'm having to google around to find the answers.

My questions are:
**How do I bring the other three phones back online?**
**How do I access the Cisco CME of the router to make changes to the quick buttons and directory on the other phones?**

I've found out that the fa0/1 interface is trunked out to two VLANs, one VLAN operates the PC's (192.168.1.0/24) and the other VLAN operates the phones (10.10.10.0/24)

Interface fa0/0 is empty so I thought that maybe if I configured that port to access the 10.10.10.0 network and set it to assign IPs by DHCP I'd be able to open the browser on my computer (that is connected to this 10.10.10.0 network after getting an IP from DHCP) and navigate to the router 10.10.10.1 through my browser and access the CME. Is this correct?

Posted below is the current running config.

**EDIT: Entire config**

```
Current configuration : 21515 bytes
!
! Last configuration change at 18:12:47 GMT Tue Dec 17 2013
! NVRAM config last updated at 10:05:30 GMT Sat Dec 14 2013
!
version 12.4
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname Router2811
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
enable secret 5 $1$lVWu$dwhlnh3hzJz9nLwt8RoDY/
enable password password
!
no aaa new-model
!
resource policy
!
clock timezone GMT -8
clock summer-time GMT recurring
!
!
ip cef
no ip dhcp use vrf connected
ip dhcp excluded-address 10.10.10.1 10.10.10.10
!
ip dhcp pool phone
   network 10.10.10.0 255.255.255.0
   default-router 10.10.10.1
   option 150 ip 10.10.10.1
!
!
ip ftp username username
ip ftp password password
ip name-server 64.2.21.107
ip name-server 64.2.21.213
!
!
!
voice-card 0
 no dspfarm
!
!
!
voice service voip
 allow-connections h323 to h323
 allow-connections h323 to sip
 allow-connections sip to h323
 allow-connections sip to sip
 supplementary-service h450.12
 h323
 sip
  registrar server expires max 3600 min 3600
!
!
voice class codec 1
 codec preference 1 g711ulaw
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
voice translation-rule 9
 rule 1 /^911$/ /911/
 rule 2 /^9\(.*\)/ /\1/
!
!
!
!
username admin privilege 15 secret 5 $1$laKi$pfrWq3A4KxaXliCisHhkl0
!
!
class-map match-all L3-to-L2_VoIP-Cntrl
 match ip dscp af31
class-map match-all L3-to-L2_VoIP-RTP
 match ip dscp ef
class-map match-all SIP
 match protocol sip
class-map match-all RTP
 match protocol rtp
!
policy-map EthOut
 class RTP
policy-map output-L3-to-L2
 class L3-to-L2_VoIP-RTP
  set cos 5
 class L3-to-L2_VoIP-Cntrl
  set cos 3
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface Loopback0
 ip address 10.1.10.2 255.255.255.0
!
interface FastEthernet0/0
 description ** DHCP Client mode **
 ip address dhcp
 ip nat outside
 ip virtual-reassembly
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface Service-Engine0/0
 ip unnumbered Loopback0
 service-module ip address 10.1.10.1 255.255.255.0
 service-module ip default-gateway 10.1.10.2
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 no ip address
 no ip mroute-cache
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface FastEthernet0/1.1
 description ** Data VLAN **
 encapsulation dot1Q 1 native
 ip address 192.168.1.2 255.255.255.0
 ip nat inside
 ip virtual-reassembly
!
interface FastEthernet0/1.2
 description ** Voice VLAN **
 encapsulation dot1Q 2
 ip address 10.10.10.1 255.255.255.0
 service-policy output output-L3-to-L2
!
ip route 10.1.10.1 255.255.255.255 Service-Engine0/0
!
!
ip http server
ip http authentication local
no ip http secure-server
ip http path flash:
ip nat inside source list 1 interface FastEthernet0/0 overload
!
access-list 1 remark SDM_ACL Category=2
access-list 1 permit 192.168.10.0 0.0.0.255
!
!
!
!
!
tftp-server flash:P0030702T023.loads
tftp-server flash:P0030702T023.sb2
tftp-server flash:P0030702T023.sbn
tftp-server flash:P0030702T023.bin
tftp-server flash:CP7902080001SCCP051117A.sbin
tftp-server flash:Analog1.raw
tftp-server flash:Analog2.raw
tftp-server flash:AreYouThere.raw
tftp-server flash:AreYouThereF.raw
tftp-server flash:Bass.raw
tftp-server flash:CallBack.raw
tftp-server flash:Chime.raw
tftp-server flash:Classic1.raw
tftp-server flash:Classic2.raw
tftp-server flash:ClockShop.raw
tftp-server flash:DistinctiveRingList.xml
tftp-server flash:Drums1.raw
tftp-server flash:Drums2.raw
tftp-server flash:FilmScore.raw
tftp-server flash:HarpSynth.raw
tftp-server flash:Jamaica.raw
tftp-server flash:KotoEffect.raw
tftp-server flash:MusicBox.raw
tftp-server flash:Piano1.raw
tftp-server flash:Piano2.raw
tftp-server flash:Pop.raw
tftp-server flash:Ring1.raw
tftp-server flash:Ring2.raw
tftp-server flash:Ring3.raw
tftp-server flash:Ring4.raw
tftp-server flash:Ring5.raw
tftp-server flash:Ring6.raw
tftp-server flash:Ring7.raw
tftp-server flash:RingList.xml
tftp-server flash:Sax1.raw
tftp-server flash:Sax2.raw
tftp-server flash:Vibe.raw
tftp-server flash:Pulse1.raw
!
control-plane
!
!
!
voice-port 0/0/0
 connection plar opx 2000
 caller-id enable
!
voice-port 0/0/1
 connection plar opx 2000
 caller-id enable
!
voice-port 0/0/2
 connection plar opx 2000
 caller-id enable
!
voice-port 0/0/3
 connection plar opx 2000
 caller-id enable
!
voice-port 0/1/0
 auto-cut-through
 operation 4-wire
 type 5
 signal immediate
 description Overhead Paging Port 0
!
voice-port 0/1/1
 auto-cut-through
 operation 4-wire
 type 5
 signal immediate
 description Overhead Paging Port 1
!
!
!
!
dial-peer cor custom
 name internal
 name local
 name domestic
 name international
 name 900
 name 976
!
!
dial-peer cor list call-internal
 member internal
!
dial-peer cor list call-local
 member local
!
dial-peer cor list call-domestic
 member domestic
!
dial-peer cor list call-international
 member international
!
dial-peer cor list call-900
 member 900
!
dial-peer cor list call-976
 member 976
!
dial-peer cor list user-internal
 member internal
!
dial-peer cor list user-local
 member internal
 member local
!
dial-peer cor list user-domestic
 member internal
 member local
 member domestic
!
dial-peer cor list user-international
 member internal
 member local
 member domestic
 member international
!
dial-peer cor list user900-internal
 member internal
 member 900
 member 976
!
dial-peer cor list user900-local
 member internal
 member local
 member 900
 member 976
!
dial-peer cor list user900-domestic
 member internal
 member local
 member domestic
 member 900
 member 976
!
dial-peer cor list user900-international
 member internal
 member local
 member domestic
 member international
 member 900
 member 976
!
!
dial-peer voice 1 pots
 description ** FXO Incoming call **
 incoming called-number .
 direct-inward-dial
 port 0/0/0
 forward-digits all
!
dial-peer voice 2 pots
 description ** FXO Incoming call **
 incoming called-number .
 direct-inward-dial
 port 0/0/1
 forward-digits all
!
dial-peer voice 3 pots
 description ** FXO Incoming call **
 incoming called-number .
 direct-inward-dial
 port 0/0/2
 forward-digits all
!
dial-peer voice 4 pots
 description ** FXO Incoming call **
 incoming called-number .
 direct-inward-dial
 port 0/0/3
 forward-digits all
!
dial-peer voice 5 pots
 description ** FXO pots dial-peer **
 destination-pattern 911
 port 0/0/0
 forward-digits all
!
dial-peer voice 6 pots
 description ** FXO pots dial-peer **
 destination-pattern 9911
 port 0/0/0
 forward-digits 3
!
dial-peer voice 7 pots
 corlist outgoing call-local
 description ** FXO pots dial-peer **
 destination-pattern 9[2-9]......
 port 0/0/0
 forward-digits 7
!
dial-peer voice 8 pots
 corlist outgoing call-domestic
 description ** FXO pots dial-peer **
 destination-pattern 91..........
 port 0/0/0
 forward-digits 11
!
dial-peer voice 9 pots
 corlist outgoing call-international
 description ** FXO pots dial-peer **
 destination-pattern 9011T
 port 0/0/0
 prefix 011
!
dial-peer voice 10 pots
 corlist outgoing call-900
 description ** FXO pots dial-peer **
 destination-pattern 91900.......
 port 0/0/0
 forward-digits 11
!
dial-peer voice 11 pots
 corlist outgoing call-976
 description ** FXO pots dial-peer **
 destination-pattern 91976.......
 port 0/0/0
 forward-digits 11
!
dial-peer voice 12 pots
 description ** FXO pots dial-peer **
 destination-pattern 911
 port 0/0/1
 forward-digits all
!
dial-peer voice 13 pots
 description ** FXO pots dial-peer **
 destination-pattern 9911
 port 0/0/1
 forward-digits 3
!
dial-peer voice 14 pots
 corlist outgoing call-local
 description ** FXO pots dial-peer **
 destination-pattern 9[2-9]......
 port 0/0/1
 forward-digits 7
!
dial-peer voice 15 pots
 corlist outgoing call-domestic
 description ** FXO pots dial-peer **
 destination-pattern 91..........
 port 0/0/1
 forward-digits 11
!
dial-peer voice 16 pots
 corlist outgoing call-international
 description ** FXO pots dial-peer **
 destination-pattern 9011T
 port 0/0/1
 prefix 011
!
dial-peer voice 17 pots
 corlist outgoing call-900
 description ** FXO pots dial-peer **
 destination-pattern 91900.......
 port 0/0/1
 forward-digits 11
!
dial-peer voice 18 pots
 corlist outgoing call-976
 description ** FXO pots dial-peer **
 destination-pattern 91976.......
 port 0/0/1
 forward-digits 11
!
dial-peer voice 19 pots
 description ** FXO pots dial-peer **
 destination-pattern 911
 port 0/0/2
 forward-digits all
!
dial-peer voice 20 pots
 description ** FXO pots dial-peer **
 destination-pattern 9911
 port 0/0/2
 forward-digits 3
!
dial-peer voice 21 pots
 corlist outgoing call-local
 description ** FXO pots dial-peer **
 destination-pattern 9[2-9]......
 port 0/0/2
 forward-digits 7
!
dial-peer voice 22 pots
 corlist outgoing call-domestic
 description ** FXO pots dial-peer **
 destination-pattern 91..........
 port 0/0/2
 forward-digits 11
!
dial-peer voice 23 pots
 corlist outgoing call-international
 description ** FXO pots dial-peer **
 destination-pattern 9011T
 port 0/0/2
 prefix 011
!
dial-peer voice 24 pots
 corlist outgoing call-900
 description ** FXO pots dial-peer **
 destination-pattern 91900.......
 port 0/0/2
 forward-digits 11
!
dial-peer voice 25 pots
 corlist outgoing call-976
 description ** FXO pots dial-peer **
 destination-pattern 91976.......
 port 0/0/2
 forward-digits 11
!
dial-peer voice 26 pots
 description ** FXO pots dial-peer **
 destination-pattern 911
 port 0/0/3
 forward-digits all
!
dial-peer voice 27 pots
 description ** FXO pots dial-peer **
 destination-pattern 9911
 port 0/0/3
 forward-digits 3
!
dial-peer voice 28 pots
 corlist outgoing call-local
 description ** FXO pots dial-peer **
 destination-pattern 9[2-9]......
 port 0/0/3
 forward-digits 7
!
dial-peer voice 29 pots
 corlist outgoing call-domestic
 description ** FXO pots dial-peer **
 destination-pattern 91..........
 port 0/0/3
 forward-digits 11
!
dial-peer voice 30 pots
 corlist outgoing call-international
 description ** FXO pots dial-peer **
 destination-pattern 9011T
 port 0/0/3
 prefix 011
!
dial-peer voice 31 pots
 corlist outgoing call-900
 description ** FXO pots dial-peer **
 destination-pattern 91900.......
 port 0/0/3
 forward-digits 11
!
dial-peer voice 32 pots
 corlist outgoing call-976
 description ** FXO pots dial-peer **
 destination-pattern 91976.......
 port 0/0/3
 forward-digits 11
!
dial-peer voice 33 voip
 description ** cue voicemail pilot number **
 translation-profile outgoing PSTN_CallForwarding
 destination-pattern 6000
 session protocol sipv2
 session target ipv4:10.1.10.1
 dtmf-relay sip-notify
 codec g711ulaw
 no vad
!
dial-peer voice 34 voip
 description ** cue auto attendant number **
 translation-profile outgoing PSTN_CallForwarding
 destination-pattern 6001
 session protocol sipv2
 session target ipv4:10.1.10.1
 dtmf-relay sip-notify
 codec g711ulaw
 no vad
!
dial-peer voice 40 pots
 description E&M port 0 to overhead
 destination-pattern 4000
 port 0/1/0
!
!
!
!
!
telephony-service
 load 7960-7940 P0030702T023
 load 7902 CP7902080001SCCP051117A
 max-ephones 36
 max-dn 108
 ip source-address 10.10.10.1 port 2000
 calling-number initiator
 system message Duanes
 time-zone 5
 voicemail 6000
 max-conferences 2 gain -6
 call-forward pattern .T
 call-forward system redirecting-expanded
 moh MOH_LO.WAV
 multicast moh 239.1.1.1 port 2000
 web admin system name cisco secret 5 $1$YBdL$OzdL4acKoWcaLAvCI1OLW1
 dn-webedit
 time-webedit
 transfer-system full-consult dss
 transfer-pattern 9.T
!
!
ephone-template  1
 softkeys idle  Redial Dnd Newcall Cfwdall Pickup
 softkeys seized  Redial Endcall Cfwdall Pickup
 softkeys alerting  Callback Endcall
 softkeys connected  Hold Trnsfer Endcall Confrn Park
!
!
ephone-template  2
 softkeys idle  Redial Dnd Newcall Pickup
 softkeys seized  Redial Endcall Pickup
 softkeys alerting  Callback Endcall
 softkeys connected  Hold Trnsfer Endcall Confrn Park
!
!
ephone-dn  1  dual-line
 number 2001
 label 2001
 description Erik-Line2
 name Erik-Line2
 preference 1
 call-forward busy 6000
 call-forward noan 6000 timeout 16
 corlist incoming user900-international
 huntstop channel
 no huntstop
 hold-alert 30 originator
!
!
ephone-dn  2  dual-line
 number 2002
 label 2002
 description Jane Doe-Line2
 name Jane Doe-Line2
 preference 1
 call-forward busy 6000
 call-forward noan 6000 timeout 16
 corlist incoming user900-international
 no huntstop
 hold-alert 30 originator
!
!
ephone-dn  3  dual-line
 number 2003
 label 2003
 description Audrey Wall
 name Audrey Wall
 preference 1
 call-forward busy 6000
 call-forward noan 6000 timeout 10
 corlist incoming user900-international
 huntstop channel
 hold-alert 30 originator
!
!
ephone-dn  4  dual-line
 number 2000
 label 2000
 description Receptionist
 name Receptionist
 call-forward noan 2100 timeout 8
 corlist incoming user-international
 huntstop channel
 no huntstop
 hold-alert 30 originator
!
!
ephone-dn  5  dual-line
 number 2001
 label 2001
 description Stan
 name Stan
 call-forward noan 6000 timeout 15
 corlist incoming user-international
 huntstop channel
 no huntstop
 hold-alert 30 originator
!
!
ephone-dn  6  dual-line
 number 2002
 label 2002
 description Jane Doe
 name Jane Doe
 call-forward noan 6000 timeout 15
 corlist incoming user-international
 huntstop channel
 no huntstop
 hold-alert 30 originator
!
!
ephone-dn  7  dual-line
 number 2003
 label 2003
 description Audrey Wall
 name Audrey Wall
 call-forward noan 6000 timeout 10
 corlist incoming user-international
 huntstop channel
 no huntstop
 hold-alert 30 originator
!
!
ephone-dn  8  dual-line
 number 2004
 label 2004
 description Amber McInerney
 name Amber McInerney
 call-forward busy 6000
 call-forward noan 6000 timeout 15
 corlist incoming user-international
 huntstop channel
!
!
ephone-dn  9  dual-line
 number 2005
 label 2005
 description Jose Conseco
 name Jose Conseco
 call-forward noan 6000 timeout 16
 corlist incoming user-international
 huntstop channel
 no huntstop
 hold-alert 30 originator
!
!
ephone-dn  10  dual-line
 number 2006
 label 2006
 description Matt Mullen
 name Matt Mullen
 call-forward noan 6000 timeout 24
 corlist incoming user900-international
 huntstop channel
 no huntstop
 hold-alert 30 originator
!
!
ephone-dn  11  dual-line
 number 2007
 label 2007
 description Delivery Area
 name Delivery Area
 call-forward busy 6000
 call-forward noan 6000 timeout 24
 corlist incoming user900-international
 hold-alert 30 originator
!
!
ephone-dn  12  dual-line
 number 2008
 label 2008
 description Brian Allen
 name Brian Allen
 call-forward noan 6000 timeout 24
 corlist incoming user900-international
 huntstop channel
 no huntstop
 hold-alert 30 originator
!
!
ephone-dn  13  dual-line
 number 2009
 label 2009
 description Time Clock
 name Time Clock
 call-forward busy 6000
 call-forward noan 6000 timeout 24
 corlist incoming user900-international
 hold-alert 30 originator
!
!
ephone-dn  14  dual-line
 number 2010
 label 2010
 description Empty Office
 name Empty Office
 call-forward busy 6000
 call-forward noan 6000 timeout 15
 corlist incoming user900-international
 hold-alert 30 originator
!
!
ephone-dn  15  dual-line
 number 2011
 label 2011
 description Tony Davis
 name Tony Davis
 call-forward noan 6000 timeout 10
 corlist incoming user900-international
 huntstop channel
 no huntstop
 hold-alert 30 originator
!
!
ephone-dn  16
 number 8000....
 mwi on
!
!
ephone-dn  17
 number 8001....
 mwi off
!
!
ephone-dn  18
 number 1000
 park-slot timeout 30 limit 4 notify 2000 only transfer 2000 retry 15 limit 2
!
!
ephone-dn  19
 number 1001
 park-slot timeout 30 limit 4 notify 2000 only transfer 2000 retry 15 limit 2
!
!
ephone-dn  20
 number 1002
 park-slot timeout 30 limit 4 notify 2000 only transfer 2000 retry 15 limit 2
!
!
ephone-dn  21
 number 1003
 park-slot timeout 30 limit 4 notify 2000 only transfer 2000 retry 15 limit 2
!
!
ephone-dn  22  dual-line
 number 2000
 label 2000
 description Receptionist-Line2
 name Receptionist-Line2
 preference 1
 call-forward busy 2100
 call-forward noan 2100 timeout 8
 corlist incoming user900-international
 huntstop channel
 no huntstop
 hold-alert 30 originator
!
!
ephone-dn  23  dual-line
 number 2004
 label 2004
 description Amber Line 2
 name Amber McInerney
 preference 1
 call-forward busy 6000
 call-forward noan 6000 timeout 16
 corlist incoming user900-international
 huntstop channel
 hold-alert 30 originator
!
!
ephone-dn  24  dual-line
 number 2100
 label Main
 call-forward noan 5000 timeout 16
 corlist incoming user900-international
 huntstop channel
 no huntstop
 hold-alert 30 originator
!
!
ephone-dn  25  dual-line
 number 2100
 label Main
 description MainLine Rollover2
 preference 1
 call-forward busy 5000
 call-forward noan 5000 timeout 16
 corlist incoming user900-international
 huntstop channel
 no huntstop
 hold-alert 30 originator
!
!
ephone-dn  26
 number 5000
 label GeneralVM
 description GeneralVM
 name GeneralVM
 call-forward busy 6000
 call-forward noan 6000 timeout 3
 corlist incoming user900-international
 hold-alert 30 originator
!
!
ephone-dn  27  dual-line
 number 2011
 label 2011
 description Tony Davis
 name Tony Davis
 preference 1
 call-forward busy 6000
 call-forward noan 6000 timeout 10
 corlist incoming user900-international
 huntstop channel
 hold-alert 30 originator
!
!
ephone-dn  28  dual-line
 number 2009
 label 2009
 description test line
 preference 1
!
!
ephone-dn  29  dual-line
 number 2012
 label 2012
 description New User
 name New User
 call-forward busy 6000
 call-forward noan 6000 timeout 12
 corlist incoming user900-international
 hold-alert 30 originator
!
!
ephone-dn  30  dual-line
 number 2006
 label 2006
 description Matt Line 2
 name Matt Mullen
 call-forward busy 6000
 call-forward noan 6000 timeout 24
 corlist incoming user900-international
 huntstop channel
 hold-alert 30 originator
!
!
ephone-dn  31  dual-line
 number 2008
 label 2008
 description Brian Allen
 name Brian Allen
 preference 1
 call-forward busy 6000
 call-forward noan 6000 timeout 24
 corlist incoming user900-international
 huntstop channel
 hold-alert 30 originator
!
!
ephone-dn  32  dual-line
 number 2005
 label 2005
 description Jose Conseco
 name Jose Conseco
 preference 1
 call-forward busy 6000
 call-forward noan 6000 timeout 16
 corlist incoming user-international
 huntstop channel
 no huntstop
 hold-alert 30 originator
!
!
ephone-dn  33  dual-line
 number 2013
 label 2013
 description Ken Garton
 name Ken Garton
 call-forward busy 6000
 call-forward noan 6000 timeout 24
 corlist incoming user-international
 huntstop channel
 hold-alert 30 originator
!
!
ephone  1
 device-security-mode none
 mac-address 0013.608F.98F3
 ephone-template 1
 speed-dial 1 4000 label "Overhead Page"
 type 7960
 button  1:4 2:22 3:24 4:25
 button  5m26
!
!
!
ephone  2
 device-security-mode none
 mac-address 0007.8599.2E3F
 ephone-template 1
 speed-dial 1 4000 label "Overhead Page"
 type 7960
 button  1:8 2:23 3:24 4:25
 button  5m26
!
!
!
ephone  3
 device-security-mode none
 mac-address 0013.C4AA.C42A
 ephone-template 1
 speed-dial 1 4000 label "Overhead Page"
 type 7960
 button  1:5 2:1 3:24 4:25
 button  5m26
!
!
!
ephone  4
 device-security-mode none
 mac-address 0013.6039.8BFA
 ephone-template 1
 speed-dial 1 4000 label "Overhead Page"
 type 7960
 button  1:6 2:2 3:24 4:25
 button  5m26
!
!
!
ephone  5
 device-security-mode none
 mac-address 0017.E013.41A9
 ephone-template 1
 username "swall"
 speed-dial 1 4000 label "Overhead Page"
 type 7960
 button  1:7 2:3 3:24 4:25
 button  5m26
!
!
!
ephone  6
 device-security-mode none
 mac-address 0017.E013.412F
 ephone-template 2
 speed-dial 1 4000 label "Overhead Page"
 type 7960
 button  1:10 2:30 3:24 4:25
 button  5m26
!
!
!
ephone  7
 device-security-mode none
 mac-address 0015.62EA.6944
 ephone-template 1
 speed-dial 1 4000 label "Overhead Page"
 type 7960
 button  1:9 2:32 3:24 4:25
 button  5m26
!
!
!
ephone  8
 device-security-mode none
 mac-address 0013.601C.1A23
 ephone-template 2
 type 7960
 button  1:11
!
!
!
ephone  9
 device-security-mode none
 mac-address 0015.621B.2A9B
 ephone-template 2
 speed-dial 1 4000 label "Overhead Page"
 type 7960
 button  1:12 2:31 3:24 4:25
 button  5m26
!
!
!
ephone  10
 device-security-mode none
 mac-address 0013.1AFF.302E
 ephone-template 2
 type 7960
 button  1:13 2:28
!
!
!
ephone  11
 device-security-mode none
 mac-address 0015.62B5.FAE2
 ephone-template 2
 type 7960
 button  1:14
!
!
!
ephone  12
 device-security-mode none
 mac-address 0017.955B.0A32
 ephone-template 1
 username "jcoffinberry"
 speed-dial 1 4000 label "Overhead Page"
 type 7960
 button  1:15 2:27 3:24 4:25
 button  5m26
!
!
!
ephone  13
 device-security-mode none
 mac-address 0017.E013.2BFC
 ephone-template 2
 username "newuser"
 button  1:29
!
!
!
ephone  14
 device-security-mode none
 mac-address 000F.341F.FE6A
 ephone-template 1
 speed-dial 1 4000 label "Overhead Page"
 type 7960
 button  1:15 2:27 3:24 4:25
 button  5m26
!
!
!
ephone  15
 device-security-mode none
 mac-address 0014.A981.86F5
 speed-dial 1 4000 label "Overhead Page"
 type 7960
 button  1:33
!
!
alias exec cue service-module service-engine 0/0 session
!
line con 0
 password !du@ne5
 login
line aux 0
line 194
 no activation-character
 no exec
 transport preferred none
 transport input all
 transport output pad telnet rlogin lapb-ta mop udptn v120 ssh
line vty 0 4
 password !du@ne5
 login
!
scheduler allocate 20000 1000
ntp clock-period 17180231
ntp master
ntp server 64.2.21.49
ntp server 64.2.21.107
!
webvpn context Default_context
 ssl authenticate verify all
 !
 no inservice
!
!
end
```

**EDIT: added the MACs of the three phones not receiving IPs.**
The three phones that are not receiving IPs have this in their status message.
ephone 15 - mac address 00:14:A9:81:86:F5
Status Message:
SEP0014A98186F5.cnf.xml

ephone 2 - mac address 00:07:85:99:2E:3F
Status Message
SEP000785992E3F.cnf.xml

ephone 8 - mac address 00:13:60:1C:1A:23
No status messages.

**EDIT: Results of show ip dhcp binding**

```
Bindings from all pools not associated with VRF:
IP address          Client-ID/              Lease expiration        Type
                    Hardware address/
                    User name
10.10.10.11         0100.0785.992e.3f       Dec 20 2013 03:52 PM    Automatic
10.10.10.15         0100.14a9.8186.f5       Dec 20 2013 03:52 PM    Automatic
10.10.10.18         0100.1360.1c1a.23       Dec 20 2013 03:52 PM    Automatic
```

Comment: post the entire config.  check the dhcp server to see if an address is getting to the phones.  If you have the time to make one, the 7960 has an RJ11/12 serial port on it. (I made a converter for one last night, in fact.)

Comment: http://docwiki.cisco.com/wiki/Cisco_IOS_Voice_Troubleshooting_and_Monitoring_--_Cisco_SIP_IP_Phone_7960_Troubleshooting If you're using a cisco "rolled" adapter ("the blue cable"), swap 3 & 6 on the RJ45 side. (note: RJ11/12 is six pins)

Comment: Can you add the output of `show ip dhcp binding`?  Specifically (as @Ricky Beam mentioned) to see if those three phones really are getting addresses.

Comment: Added results of `show ip dhcp binding`.

Comment: Just as a side note: My favorite part of this config, is that Jane Doe and Jose Conseco work there.  :)

Comment: Haha, ya just wanted to impersonalize it a little bit...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dhcp server shows they do actually have an address.  The status messages suggest they aren't able to find all the files they're looking for; the telephony-service should be creating those, but I don't see a `create cnf-files` in your config.  `show telephony-service tftp-bindings` will show what configs it's created and mapped.  The SCCP firmware requires option 66 (tftp server), not option 150 -- the phones will remember the last server if dhcp doesn't present one. (it can be manually configured as well.)

(even without most of the files, it'll still boot and register with the CM. I was updating eBay'd 7960's that weren't known to my CM last night. They only needed to see: OS79XX.TXT, SEPDefault.cnf, and XMLDefault.cnf.xml, and the firmware files)

Comment: I'm sorry, bare with me. Where can you tell that the phones are getting IPs? In the `show ephone summary` there's 8 ephones without IPs.

If I run a `create cnf-files` command will it generate the cnf.xml files I need and put them in the /cme/ directory of system: for me?

And where did you see the SCCP option? Thank you for your help!

Comment: SCCP vs. SIP. It's the protocol the phones (and CM) run. ephone's are SCCP. The dhcp bindings output shows those three ephones were given addresses.

Comment: So do you think if I run `create cnf-files` and then a `restart ephone` where `ephone` is the phone # of the offline phones I can get them to come back online?

Comment: Running the `create cnf-files` command caused the three downed phones to come back online. Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

> **How do I access the Cisco CME of the router to make changes to the quick buttons and directory on the other phones?**

1. Enable the http server on the router. (`ip http server`, which you have)
2. Download the CME GUI files from [Cisco](http://software.cisco.com/download/release.html?mdfid=277641082&softwareid=282786567&release=10.0&relind=AVAILABLE&rellifecycle=&reltype=latest) *that matches the version of IOS on the router*. (CCO account and service contract required)
3. Go to http://[router ip]/telephony_service.html

I don't know the exact version you're running, so I cannot say what version you need.  Any serious configuration must be done from the CLI. (your config was not made by the GUI)